# Pycharm converts whitespace and won't convert back

Tags: python, whitespace, pycharm

I am having an issue with Pycharm where certain files tracked by git will show up as having been modified when I haven't done anything but visit the file. Usually the modifications are tabs being changed to spaces or vice-versa, or tabs being added to/removed from empty lines. Once this kind of modification is made, I can't seem to roll back the changes no matter what I do. I have "keep indents on empty lines" set everywhere it can be set in settings, but Pycharm will still remove indents on some empty lines, and even when I re-add them or revert local changes to the document, as soon as I navigate away from the file it will show as modified again, and the tabs have once again been removed...I assume this is something that I am doing unknowingly, or a setting that I have set rather than a bug in Pycharm, but it is driving me crazy! Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: Just a personal recommendation: Let PyCharm convert tabs to spaces and stick with it. That's my preferred setting for all IDEs. And I see no advantage of tabs in the context of source code. Most IDEs have a rather intelligent code indentation anyway.

Comment: For the most part I agree, but I am working with an existing code base that is mostly indented with tabs, not spaces.

Comment: Have you tried the Preferences>Editor>General>Other>"Strip trailing spaces on Save" option? And have you tried setting "Tabs and Spaces" for the Python code style (Preferences>Editor>Code style>Python>Tabs and Spaces>"Use tab character")?

Comment: My tab settings are as they should be under Python, but it was the "Strip trailing spaces on Save" option that did the trick. I had it set for "Modified lines" and changing it to "None" seems to have fixed the problem! I thought that this setting only applied to whitespace at the end of the file, so I had ignored it. If you post this as an answer I will I will accept it as correct so that others with the same problem can benefit from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two more settings you might want to check:

1. Preferences > Editor > General > Other > Strip trailing spaces on Save
2. Preferences > Editor > Code style > Python > Tabs and Spaces > Use tab character

Answer (score 0):

To keep PyCharm from removing whitespace, do this:

Change INDENT_TO_CARET_ON_PASTE to **false** in editor.xml if it exists, that worked for me ...

```
<application>
  <component name="CodeInsightSettings">
    <option name="REFORMAT_ON_PASTE" value="1" />
    <option name="INDENT_TO_CARET_ON_PASTE" value="false" />
  </component>
  <component name="EditorSettings">
    <option name="IS_VIRTUAL_SPACE" value="true" />
    <option name="STRIP_TRAILING_SPACES" value="None" />
  </component>
</application>
```

Fixed: PyCharm was destroying vertical alignment readability I spent so much time to achieve and it was driving me mad, scrunched code is inefficient. v2020.2.5

To find that file: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#config-directory

Or rename the file and restart. On changing a setting, it will be recreated with only that new change that was made. (Note my settings file might have been from a much earlier version long ago, now upgraded.)

***Where is the checkbox for that in the gui?**  File > Settings ... ?* *... INDENT_TO_CARET_ON_PASTE*

Comment: The setting for indent is not logically a control of whitespace removal so clearly a bug they should fix